# gtag Linker not working on JS form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, gtag.js

I used correct google tagging to enable cross-domain tracking. When the form is submitted by clicking on submit button the `?ga=...` will be added to the destination URL but, it won't be added if I trigger the submit event by JS.

Code is as follows:

```
<head>
    <script>
        //All other common JS code exist
        gtag('set', 'linker', {
            'domains': ['example.com'],
            'decorate_forms': true
        });
        gtag('config', 'UA-...');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="https://example.com/a/b">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <button id="bt">Click to submit form using JS</button> 
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#bt', function(e){
            $('form').submit();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

If I add submit button to form and click on it directly the destination will be something like `https://example.com/a/b?_ga=...`. However, when I submit the form via JS, destination URL is just like the form action without GA appendix.

I have to note that I'm using gtag and not GTM.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in two different ways:

**Method 1**
We can change the submit trigger to a click trigger on the submit button. Don't know why but, it solves the issue :)

```
$(document).on('click', '#bt', function(e){
    $('form button[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
});
```

**Method 2**
We can handle anything we want in the submit event instead of the click event on some other button other than submit.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
    //Do your stuff and handle the event
    return true;
});
```

Although the problem seems to be solved, the main question still exists and it seems it is pointing to a potential bug for gtag or jquery `form.submit()`. Therefore, if you can provide any solution or answer for the open question, go ahead and publish your post and I'll make your answer as a correct one.